# Animate UIButton down in Swift

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uibutton, jquery-animate

I'm making my first game in `Swift` and I was wondering how I could animate the buttons in Z position (or downscale and upscale) when the user presses the button.

I though that I found the answer but everything I find is written in `Objective-C` and since I'm new to coding it's pretty hard for me to translate `Obj-C` to `Swift`.

*This is what I found:*

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

//animates button 25 pixels right and 25 pixels down. Customize
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x + 25, button.frame.origin.y + 25, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [button setFrame:newFrame];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Well I don't know what it says in Obj-C so I'm looking for someone that could help me translate that to swift so I can implement it in my code.

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
@IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    button = sender as UIButton

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
        self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x + 25, self.button.frame.origin.y + 25, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height)
    })

}
```

for more information read this article http://mathewsanders.com/prototyping-iOS-iPhone-iPad-animations-in-swift/

Comment: oh, sorry for the downvote... I've nested my buttons in a lot of views and figured out your code works fine; stackoverflow won't let me upvote it